# Site indexed with cache folder

Tags: 6, caching

I'm using boost module 6.x-1.21 version and I noticed that one url is indexed with cache folder something like

> http://www.example.com/cache/normal/forum/623_.html.gz

will I block the this folder in ROBOT.txt file like this `Disallow: /cache/`

Is this correct way ? please suggest me, I'm not sure to do this.

Below is the code for boost module .htaccess file

```
 ### BOOST START ###

  # Gzip Cookie Test
  RewriteRule ^(.*)boost-gzip-cookie-test\.html cache/perm/boost-gzip-cookie-test\.html\.gz [L,T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]

  # GZIP - Cached css & js files
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(boost-gzip)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} !gzip
  RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css\.gz -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css\.gz [L,QSA,T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js\.gz -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js\.gz [L,QSA,T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

  # NORMAL - Cached css & js files
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css [L,QSA,T=text/css]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js [L,QSA,T=text/javascript]

  # Caching for anonymous users
  # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR request came from this server
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add|comment/reply))|(/(edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID
  RewriteRule .* - [S=7]

  # GZIP
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(boost-gzip)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} !gzip
  RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html\.gz -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html\.gz [L,T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml\.gz -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml\.gz [L,T=text/xml,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.json\.gz -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.json\.gz [L,T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

  # NORMAL
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml [L,T=text/xml]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.json -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.json [L,T=text/javascript]

  ### BOOST END ###
```

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. 1) The page been cached is a compressed page(.gz) mean that somewhere in your htaccess may have been a wrong code.2) You should not Disallow but 301 redirect to point at the right page.We need more info as the htaccess code and the boost module version

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the htaccess.Can you Install the latest dev? First make sure you have make a backup!!!!